# Included CSS not loading Images and Fonts

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

I have create a dynamic CSS loader, It's working fine but It didn't load CSS `Images` and `Font-Faces`! Any ideas about this situation?

My CSS loader code:

```
<?php
    $mainRoot = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    // Set desierd header for Content-Type
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
    // Load Core Css
    include $mainRoot . '/css/site-style.css';
?>
```

And I call the above script like the below file, Also I renamed `css_loader.php` to `css_loader.css` through `htaccess` rewrite rules.

```
<link type="text/css" href="mysite/css_loader.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: My first guess would be that the script is looking in the wrong directory. So from then it's guessing for me, but from what it seems, the root for the css is the root of the site, so all paths should be relative to that. But to test, you can just put some test images (with all different text in them or so) in relevant locations, give them all the same name and see which image is loaded.

Comment: What are your rewrite rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably that the image are references using their relative path.
ie:

```
background-image: url('../images/header.jpg');
```

When you use a loader - the browser will use the new css path ie: mysite/css_loader.css as the base for those image paths.

If you can .. change the image paths in your css to be absolute links like

```
background-image: url('/assets/images/header.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

If this css is used for other purposes, the links are likely relative to /css/. Because you've included it with your php, it will now look like an internal stylesheet, and the browser will now look relative to the html page's url (likely not /css/.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try placing a static css file in the directory mysite.

It looks like you have problems with relative paths in the CSS file.

In the static file, you can try all combinations of including/omitting the `mysite/` or `css/` part, or prepending `../`.

You can also open a network traffic analyzer (like the one in Network tools integrated in Firefox) and see what files the browser tries to load. This way you can observe what files does the browser really try to download and change the relative paths in the CSS file appropriately.